# Asp.net mvc3 periodic refresh of results without reloading the page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using asp.net MVC3 for a website that displays in a view a query result (managed in the controller) using a foreach.

What I want to do now is to automatically refresh the output of the query every tot time, without refreshing the page.

How can I do that using ajax?

This is the code of the View:

```
@{
    string firstTime = "";
}
 @foreach( var database in Model)
 {

        if (!(firstTime == database.DB))
        {
          <h3> @database.DB </h3>
        }

           <div class="logContainer" onclick="location.href='/logs/Details?databaseID=@database.DB&exceptionName=@database.Exception&exceptionsOccurred=@database.Count';">
                <div class="counter"><b>@database.Count</b></div> 
                <div class="exceptionName"> Exceptions of Type: @database.Exception</div>
                <div class="date">Siste: @database.LastOccurred</div>
           </div>
       <hr />

     firstTime = database.DB; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *every time*? At some regular intervals without user interaction?

Comment: every tot time, user or programmer defined.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval) javascript method to send AJAX requests to the server at regular intervals and refresh the corresponding part of the DOM. For example if you wanted to refresh the contents every 10 seconds:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.post('@Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller")', function(result) {
        $('#results').html(result);
    });
}, 10 * 1000);
```

This will send an AJAX request to the controller action which in turn could return a partial view containing the updated results:

```
pubilc ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    SomeViewModel model = ...
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

The result of this partial view will then be injected into some DOM element with `id="results"`.

Comment: I'm using Linq2Sql and I have difficulties in importing the partial view in the view since I have to specify the type of the model, and in the controller I return a Linq anonymous type. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: @Attila, by defining a strongly typed view model and specifying it in your view. That's what I would recommend you as good practice. Don't pass anonymous objects to your views as they make them weakly typed.

Answer (score 2):

You could either pass the query result using JSON and render the HTML yourself from javascript, or separate the for-each code to a different partial view, and using jQuery's $.ajax method change the query result's div html with the new response

Answer (score 0):

Why not put your data in to an existing grid control such as [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/), which is lightweight pretty fast and extensible.  Then, using a javascript timer, tell the data table to refresh it's contents.

I've used this with MVC3 with great effect.

Comment: I checked them out, but I've almost finished the work I'm doing and I don't want to integrate a new component, have you got a solution to just refresh the div of the results?